# data.table merge with no obvious / unique join key

Tags: r, merge, data.table

**Problem:** Suppose I have the below `data.table` object (ex) which I want to merge with `date_frame` object such that I get the desired output. The desired output shall be in the form such that the C_ states show only up once per CURRENT_DATE. However, if there is more than one E state per iid then these E states (with respective start date) shall show up multiple times per CURRENT_DATE. Any idea how to do that? Many thanks!!

```
## Desired Output
iid   state   start       CURRENT_DATE
1        E    2020-01-02   2020-03-31
1        C_1  2020-01-03   2020-03-31
1        C_2  2020-01-05   2020-03-31
1        E    2020-01-06   2020-03-31
1        E    2020-01-08   2020-03-31
2        E    2020-01-10   2020-03-31
1        E    2020-01-02   2020-04-01
....
```

**Toy example**

```
library(data.table)

ex <- data.table(iid = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
                 state = c("E", "C_1", "C_2", "E", "E", "E"),
                 start = c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-10"))

s <- seq.Date(from = ex[, min(ymd(start))],
              to = Sys.Date(),
              "days")

date_frame <- CJ(CURRENT_DATE = s, iid = unique(ex$iid))

## not working
merge(ex, date_frame, all = TRUE, by = "iid")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
ex[CJ(CURRENT_DATE=seq(max(start), min(start), by="-1 day"), iid, unique=TRUE), 
    on=.(iid), allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

output:

```
    iid state      start CURRENT_DATE
 1:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-02
 2:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-02
 3:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-02
 4:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-02
 5:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-02
 6:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-02
 7:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-03
 8:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-03
 9:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-03
10:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-03
11:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-03
12:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-03
13:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-04
14:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-04
15:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-04
16:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-04
17:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-04
18:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-04
19:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-05
20:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-05
21:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-05
22:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-05
23:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-05
24:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-05
25:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-06
26:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-06
27:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-06
28:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-06
29:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-06
30:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-06
31:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-07
32:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-07
33:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-07
34:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-07
35:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-07
36:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-07
37:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-08
38:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-08
39:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-08
40:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-08
41:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-08
42:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-08
43:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-09
44:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-09
45:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-09
46:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-09
47:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-09
48:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-09
49:   1     E 2020-01-02   2020-01-10
50:   1   C_1 2020-01-03   2020-01-10
51:   1   C_2 2020-01-05   2020-01-10
52:   1     E 2020-01-06   2020-01-10
53:   1     E 2020-01-08   2020-01-10
54:   2     E 2020-01-10   2020-01-10
    iid state      start CURRENT_DATE
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
ex <- data.table(iid = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
    state = c("E", "C_1", "C_2", "E", "E", "E"),
    start = c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-10"))
ex[, start := as.IDate(start)]
```